# Dividing 100 evenly by a dynamic variable

Tags: c#

I am assigning employees a random integer percentage of 100. This percentage is based on how many employees we have and must total to 100.

If we have 4 employees, I would perhaps want to generate a split such as 80-10-5-5.. if we had 2 employees. The more random the percentages are, the better.

I'm not sure how to accomplish this elegantly without a ton of different if statements but even then the randomness would be limited I feel.

Comment: What about: choose a random.order of employees. Then assign the first one a random number between 0-100. Then calculate 100- this number. Generate a new random.nunver beween 0- calculated and assign.it to.the.second.employee. repeat.

Comment: Show more expected output.

Comment: lalala's answer would end up having employee 1 average 50, employee 2 average 25, 3 12.5... sascha's answer is more appropriate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just assign each employee a random number in a certain range (range ist up to you). Than calculate the sum of the random numbers. Last step: devide each random number by the sum which gives you the percentage.

Example: random number 3, 9, 7
Sum = 19
Percentages: 3/19=16%, 9/19=47%, 7/19=37%
(Values are rounded.)

Comment: I love this solution. It's elegant and it demonstrates the magic of math and numbers. If you happened to have some documentation as  to why this works I would love to read it! Cheers

Comment: I don't have any documentation at hand, but it works, because it uses the definition of percentage, which is a value in relation to a base value where your base value is the sum of all random values. Sorry, I can't really explain that in English. Maybe someone else could help me out. :)

Answer (score 0):

I have written a sample code for this:

```
        int no_of_employees = 4;
        int total_percentage = 100;
        List<int> tempNumberList = new List<int>();
        List<int> finalNumberList = new List<int>();
        Random random = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < no_of_employees; i++)
        {
            tempNumberList.Add(random.Next(total_percentage));
        }
        int sum = tempNumberList.Sum();
        foreach(int number in tempNumberList)
        {
            finalNumberList.Add((number * total_percentage) / sum); 
        }
        if(finalNumberList.Sum() != total_percentage)
        {
            finalNumberList[0] = finalNumberList[0] + (total_percentage - finalNumberList.Sum());
        }
```

Please feel free to improve the logic if necessary at all.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
var random = new Random();
var percentages = new List<int>();
int remainder = 100;

for (int i = 0; i < employeesCount; i++)
{
    int percentage = random.Next(remainder);
    percentages.Add(percentage);

    remainder -= percentage;
}

percentages[percentages.Count - 1] += remainder;
```

Note that

- the last line solves the rounding issue in case the percentages' sum is not 100
- a solution using only LINQ is also doable although less readable and probably with an impact on performance (using Aggregate for instance introduces the creation of an anonymous type)
- I'm not 100% sure this solution guarantees equal probability (especially the last employee's case)